# Prevent page from loading in javascript?

Tags: jquery, popup, preventdefault, onunload

I am using javascript `onunload` function to display a popup form when user is trying to leave the page, it shows the popup but it can't prevent page load.

Here's my code

```
$(window).bind('unload', function(e) {  
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        modal: true
    }); 

    e.preventDefault();
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        modal: true
    }); 
    return "Look at the modal";
});
```

Without Jquery:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
   var message = "Your pop up message",
   e = e || window.event;
   // For IE ,Firefox and Chrome
   if (e) {
      // your functions go here
      console.log("test");
      e.returnValue = message;

   } else {
      // For Safari
      //your functions go here
      console.log('test');
      return message;
    };
};
```

Comment: but it is not compatible with ipad or iphone

Comment: I don't know any solution with jquery but check the 'Without Jquery' solution i added on my answer.